# We have Arduino IDE code that needs to stop after a set number of "revolutions"

Tags: arduino-ide

We have Arduino IDE code that oscillates a plate on a lead screw powered by stepper motor to move back and forth.

We have the lead screw move 8 mm in one direction, then 8 mm in the opposite direction, for a total displacement of 16 mm. After this movement we have a counter that will then count as 1 "revolution" essentially. After reaching a specified count that program will stop.

Currently the program continues to run indefinitely. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

```cpp
// Include the AccelStepper library:
#include <AccelStepper.h>

// Define stepper motor connections and motor interface type.
// Motor interface type must be set to 1 when using a driver:
#define dirPin 2
#define stepPin 3
#define motorInterfaceType 1

// Create a new instance of the AccelStepper class:
AccelStepper stepper = AccelStepper(motorInterfaceType, stepPin, dirPin);

void setup() {
  // Set the maximum speed and acceleration:
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(40000);
  stepper.setAcceleration(20000);
}

void loop() {
  static int counter = 0; // Initialize a counter variable and start at 0

  // Set the target position:
  stepper.moveTo(400); // is in steps. setting to default

  // Run to target position with set speed and acceleration/deceleration:
  stepper.runToPosition();

  delay(0);

  // Move back to zero:
  stepper.moveTo(0);
  stepper.runToPosition();

  delay(0); //microseconds
  counter++; //adds 1 to the counter

  if (counter >= 2) {
    return; //exit the loop
  }
}
```

Comment: IED means "improvised explosive device"

Comment: [IED disambiguation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IED)

Comment: What is "IED"? Do you mean [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)? Or *[intelligent electronic device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_electronic_device)*? Or [Industrial Emissions Directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_Emissions_Directive)? Or something else?

Answer (score 4):

```
if (counter >= 2) {
    return; //exit the loop
  }
```

The return statement will end the loop, but the loop function is called over and over repeatedly.  So it will just start over again.

There are a few possibilities here.  You can replace the `return` statement with `while(1);` which will lock up execution there until the board is reset.

If you don't need the loop function to repeat ever then you can simply move all of your code into the setup function as it will only run once.  Then the loop function can just be empty.

And lastly, you could add a boolean variable and put the code you want to run only sometimes under an if statement that checks that variable.  At the end of the process you set the variable to false to stop the other code from running.  This would allow you to add code later to set it back at the press of a button or something in case you wanted the option to start the process again.

```
bool running = true;
void loop(){
  if(running){
      // do things
  }
  if (counter >= 2){
    running = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `exit(0)` and `abort()` should also work. On AVR at least they are equivalent to `while(1);`, while more explicit about the intent.

Comment: I thought exit(0) was broken?  Why did I think that?  Was it ever?